# iOS: How to check is Haptic Feedback enabled (iOS Settings)

Tags: ios, feedback, haptic-feedback, uifeedbackgenerator

Is it possible to read the option in the iOS settings whether the haptic feedback is activated or deactivated?

Comment: do you want to check whether the haptic is supported by the device or not?

Comment: In the iOS system settings it is possible to deactivate the haptic feedback. I would like to read this option.

Comment: I think there is no native way to check whether it is haptic feedback is disable or not.

Comment: Therefore I asked this question :-). I would like to replace dialogues with haptic feedback. To do this, I need to know whether the feedback notification is taking place. Unfortunately, I couldn't find anything in the Apple Inc. documentary. It is also possible with the camera and the microphone.

Answer (score 3):

**Response**

Apple doesn't provide any API to check if a *Vibrations* are enabled on a device. Only one thing which can be tested is a device compatibility with Core Haptics Framework

> Not all devices support Core Haptics. For example, iPad and iPod touch
>   don’t support haptic feedback, so calls to Core Haptics won’t result
>   in haptics. [source](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corehaptics/preparing_your_app_to_play_haptics)

**Remarks:**

*System Haptics* were renamed and now are called *Vibrations* in *Settings* app. This technology in Apple Developer Documentation for Developers is called *Haptic Feedback*.

Comment: Please post this as a comment as its referencing another answer on the StackOverflow. Follow the guidelines for the same [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: The question I asked related to haptic feedback. This does not mean Force Touch. A user can activate or deactivate the system haptics under iOS Settings / Sounds and Haptics. I would like to read the value here.